# Are continuous bounded functions a subspace of $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I have a problem where I need to work with functions that are square-integrable, bounded and continuous, i.e. the space

$ L^2 \supset X = \left\{ f \in L^2 \mid f \text{ bounded, continuous}\right\} $

equipped with the $L^2$ norm.

I have a hard time understanding if this is a subspace of $L^2$ because I do not know how to show whether or not $X$ is complete under the $L^2$ norm.

Any text regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: A subspace is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. Just use the triangle inequality to bound norms such as $\|af+bg\|_2$, for $f,g\in X$.

Comment: @AlexR. I suppose I should write "complete", not "closed". I wish to know if $X$ itself is a Hilbert space.

Comment: Hint: do you know a member of $L^2$ that is not in $X$?  Is it the limit (in $L^2$ norm) of functions that are in $X$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael The series $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{n(|x| - 1)}}$ for $n > 0$ is square-integrable and bounded, but converges towards a discontinuous function, right?

Comment: OK, that would do.